# Copy from local to amazon ec2

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, terminal, ubuntu-14.04, scp

I'm trying to copy .crt file to my server but it says permission denied. What am I doing wrong? I tried without `sudo` too but the same error happens. What am I missing?

I can ssh without a problem.

`Elaine-MacBook-Pro:pride byrne$`

```
sudo scp -i pride.pem ssl/pride/b1ea8634211f5783.crt ubuntu@ec2-52-78-yyy-xxx.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com:/etc/apache2/ssl
scp: /etc/apache2/ssl/b1ea8634211f5783.crt: Permission denied
```

`Elaine-MacBook-Pro:pride byrne$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The amazone ec2 user is `ubuntu`, which does not have permission in `/etc/apache2/ssl` folder. So first copy file to a folder where the remote user has permission(eg: home folder). After use `sudo` to move file from there to `/etc/apache2/ssl` folder.

Comment: Genius. Thank you so much :)